# Как добавить скрытые поля в Woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите, пожалуйста как мне добавить эти скрытые поля в оформлении заказа Woocommerce. Очевидно я не знаю PHP и поэтому нужна Ваша помощь)

```
<input name="utm-source" type="hidden" value="<?=$_COOKIE['utm_source']?>">
<input name="utm-medium" type="hidden" value="<?=$_COOKIE['utm_medium']?>">
<input name="utm-compaign" type="hidden" value="<?=$_COOKIE['utm_compaign']?>">
<input name="utm-content" type="hidden" value="<?=$_COOKIE['utm_content']?>">
<input name="utm-term" type="hidden" value="<?=$_COOKIE['utm_term']?>">
```

Comment: Ну добавить не проблема но.. два вопроса: 1 - а что дальше-то? 2. Что ты будешь делать с кодом, если ты "Очевидно не знаешь PHP" и ВП тем более?

Comment: Что делать дальше, я знаю.

Comment: Уверен что не знаешь. Потому что их нужно еще как минимум принять и что-то дальше делать (передать, обработать и тд).

Comment: Ну так помоги, зачем что-то пытаться доказать?)